# How to Accept Standard Input in C from the Linux Command Line

Tags: c, linux, command-line

I am trying to accept a string from the standard input in Linux, take the given string and change the 'A'(s) and 'a'(s) to '@', and output the altered string.

In linux I am running this: echo "This problem is an EASY one" | ./a2at

My a2at.c program contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *words[])
{   

    int i = 0;
    char b[256];

    while(words[i] != NULL)
    {
    b[i] = *words[i];

        if(b[i] =='a' || b[i]=='A')
          {
           b[i] = '@';
          }

    printf("%c",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated! I know that I am pretty far off from the right code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code is far from correct. What is the correct syntax to accept standard input from the linux command line? I want to get a string and change some of the characters, then display the new string.

Comment: Yeah, you are confusing command-line arguments and stdin.  See @BLUEPIXY comment above.

Comment: @Np938 What BLUEPIXY said. Type `man stdio` into the command line for all the standard IO functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BLUEPIXY said in his comment, you could use getchar function from stdio.h, just do man getchar in your shell to have more details about the usages. This code could help you, but don't hesitate to use the man command :) !

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;

  while ((c=getchar()) && c!=EOF) {

     if (c == 'a' || c== 'A')
       c = '@';

     write(1, &c, 1); // Or printf("%c", c);

    }

  return (0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) in order to read a single character at a time, or [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) in order to read a complete line each time.

The easiest solution would be to use `getch` in a simple infinite loop:

```
while (1) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF) {
        break;
    } else if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A') {
        putchar('@');
    } else {
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```